# How to enable Keychain Sharing capability in Xcode 8 through command line (xcodebuild)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ios10, xcode8

With Xcode 7.x we used to build our cordova application through command line, passing code sign identity and everything through the **xcodebuild** cli tool.

With the new updated Xcode 8 and a new library in our app we need to have the **Keychain Sharing** capability enabled. We cannot find any way to do this via cli and the only way to make it work is to open the Xcode project and manually click the enable checkbox.

This solution however, breaks our build scripts since we want to have an automatic build process in a newly created project (cordova add platform ios).

We tried using https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Keychain-Sharing/ but it still does not work.

Anyone managed or knows how to enable capabilities programmatically?
Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Hi ! I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution to enable Keychain sharing capability through command line ?

Comment: @nbe_42 - I am in the same situation. I want to enable health kit permission with command line.

Answer (score 0):

We have finally solved the issue internally using a cordova hook.
They can be configured for any Cordova phase, see documentation here : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/

The hook we implemented was highly inspired of an existing hook picked on Github (link below), with small ajustements to fit our specific project structure.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/hooks/ios/install_entitlements.js

Comment: The link has became broken